# Rotating UIView with button in it

Tags: iphone, uiview, rotation, imageview

I'm trying to rotate a UIview which has in the top left corner a UIButton with the action:

`NSLog@"hello";`

Now I rotate the UIView 180° and the button is now in the right bottom corner. But the button fires its action only if I press in the top left corner... so its like the buttons position has changed but its action stays at the same place as before the rotation?

I rotate the View with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

rotationAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI], 
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75 * M_PI],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5 * M_PI], 
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0 * M_PI], nil]; 
rotationAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;


rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
rotationAnimation.duration = 10.0;

CALayer *layer = [rotateView layer];
[layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: Put your rotating animation code for details

Answer (score 0):

Use CGAFFINETRANSFORM for rotaion

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265);
    yourView.transform=transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: yes i triedd, but the i cant press the button while its moving.